# Does Keras SGD optimizer implement batch, mini-batch, or stochastic gradient descent?

Tags: neural-networks, keras, stochastic-gradient-descent

I am a newbie in Deep Learning libraries and thus decided to go with **Keras**. While implementing a NN model, I saw the `batch_size` parameter in `model.fit()`.

Now, I was wondering if I use the `SGD` optimizer, and then set the `batch_size = 1`, `m` and `b`, where `m` = no. of training examples and 1 < `b` < `m`, then I would be actually implementing **Stochastic**, **Batch** and **Mini-Batch Gradient Descent** respectively. However, on the other hand, I felt using **SGD** as the optimizer would by default ignore the `batch_size` parameter, since **SGD** stands for **Stochastic Gradient Descent** and it should always use a batch_size of 1 (i.e use a single data point for each iteration of gradient descent).

I would be grateful if someone could clarify as to which of the above two cases is true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works just as you suggest. `batch_size` parameter does exactly what you would expect: it sets the size of the batch:

> - **batch_size**: `Integer` or `None`. Number of samples per gradient update. If unspecified, batch_size will default to 32.

From programming point of view, Keras decouples the weight update formula parameters specific to each optimizer (learning rate, momentum, etc.) from the global training properties (batch size, training length, etc.) that are share between methods. It is matter of convenience—there is no point in having optimizers SGD, MBGD, BGD that all do the same thing just with different batch size.

Comment: Sorry, but how does this specify Gradient vs Stochastic Gradient versus mini-batch Gradient?  
A setting of 1 would be regular Gradient descent, right?  
A setting other than 1 would be Stochastic.  
There is no way to use mini-batch, as you are not saying "never use all samples". You are only saying "update after this many samples"

Comment: If you specify `batch_size` to be the size of the whole dataset, you get *batch gradient descent* (i.e. nothing stochastic). Anything smaller is *mini-batch g.d.*, which is stochastic. Whether we call the special case of batch size = 1 something else, that's just a matter of nomenclature.

Comment: @JanKukacka, thank you for clearing this up. I had to re-read a few things as well.

Comment: @JanKukacka you should update your answer with your comment.